# Does the Hall effect increase the resistance of a wire?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrical-resistance, hall-effect

If a current in a wire is flowing perpendicular to a magnetic field, the Hall effect is observed. This effect is caused by the forces from magnetic fields *pushing* the electrons to one side of the wire. So, does it increase the resistance of the wire, as there is now less area for the current to flow through due to one side of the wire being occupied by these (assumed to be) immobile electrons?

Comment: Are the electrons on the sides actually immobile? I always thought they just drifted along with the rest.

Comment: Alright, I will have to say I am not sure. Hopefully someone would clarify it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the answer is no! See page 7 on in http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/qhe.pdf. Current is a measure of how fast the charges are moving in a particular direction; the Hall effect gives the electrons a component to their velocity perpendicular to the electric field. Another way of saying this is that the force on the electrons is $\bf{F}=-e\bf{E}-e\bf{v}\times\bf{B}$; adding a magnetic field doesn't mean the electrons flow any slower or any less in the $\bf{E}$ direction, they just now also have a velocity in the $\bf{B}$.

Answer (score 1):

The effect is transient. The magnetic force causes electrical polarisation. In the stationary state the magnetic force is compensated by the electric field due to this polarisation. This very small gradient in charge density does not influence conductivity.